# Migrating Dynamodb to Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-dynamodb, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable, google-cloud-spanner

Currently we are migrating Dynamodb table to Spanner. Since DynamoDb is a nosql database with indexing, it become a difficult task to migrate NOSQL to relational database. The only reason we are migrating it to Spanner is because of secondary indexing. But after migrating few tables, we are witnessing the latency issues in Spanner. Initially we were planned to migrate it to Cloud BigTable, but unfortunately it doesn't support secondary index. Now because of latency issue and high read/write traffic, Spanner performance is going down. Do we have any other data stores in GCP, which would be more suitable with this kind of use case, where we can have nosql as well as secondary index? We have around 200 TB's of data in DynamoDb.

Comment: Did you increase the number of Spanner nodes during the data load?

Comment: We have enough nodes to perform the smooth load, but actual problem arise during peak times, when traffic increases drastically. During peak hours, the latency goes above board which result in lag in front-end side.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Spanner documentation [Quotas & Limits](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/quotas), for improved performance, you should have a node for every 2 TB of data that you have on it. Considering that, I would recommend you to take a look at your nodes and raise the number of them that you have, active right now, yo improve the performance of your database.

On this documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/instances#regional-best-practices), you have the best practices to configure a Spanner as it's best possible performance.

In case this doesn't help, could you please take a look at the documentation [Troubleshooting performance regressions](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/troubleshooting-performance-regressions)? This way, you can take a further look at what might be affecting the performance of your Spanner.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: We are facing issues like index cluttering, latencies and many more. We already have enough nodes to manage this much traffic. We have multiple tables with 16 secondary index in same instance.

Comment: Hi @miles212 were you able to take a look at the [troubleshooting documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/troubleshooting-performance-regressions) that I provided? It should help narrow down the cause for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to firebase in datastore mode. It has secondary indexes and basically is serverless and practically unlimited in throughput. And is a nosql db as well

Comment: We were not getting the appropriate performance if the data size increase above 30TB. So we went for Spanner. Still spanner performance is better than datastore.

Comment: I use both Spanner and Datastore. 30TB means nothing to datastore and it is not possible to say without caveats who is faster. Datastore is always very fast if you take into consideration your resultset. Dataset is not a concern so it is very easy, reliable and predictable. In Spanner you have to be concerned with execution plan strategy and the case where it will excel is where there are joins.